# React Native ImagePicker causes Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, imagepicker

I'm trying to select a picture from the gallery via ImagePicker.
It doesn't matter which ImagePicker i try, 'expo-image-picker' or 'react-native-image-crop-picker' I always face the error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

I dont try to call a hook outside a function..
But when I select a picture I return a right response:

```
{"cropRect": {"height": 2242, "width": 1682, "x": 1155, "y": 0}, "height": 400, "mime": "image/jpeg", "modificationDate": "1695307585000", "path": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.clip/files/Pictures/4e0ae973-fd55-43ba-9758-34119952b375.jpg", "size": 103041, "width": 300}
```

The code looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  NativeModules,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  ImageBackground,
  Pressable,
} from "react-native";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-crop-picker";

export default function ProfileScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);

  async function changeProfilePicture() {
    await ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
    }).then((image) => {
      console.log(image);
    });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.ViewStyle}>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.PressableProfilePictureStyle}
        onPress={() => changeProfilePicture()}
      >
        <Feather name="edit" size={30} color="black" />
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it wasn't about the Image Picker. Its was about the fact that the Socket connection disconnected and connected several times when opening the picker.

Comment: If you fixed it, please mark your answer as correct.

Comment: still: "You can accept your own answer in 5 hours"

Comment: when you post my post again, you will get the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

In the onPress function there's a missing pair of brackets.

> onPress={()=> { changeProfilePicture() } }>

I don't know if it's relevant but in the return statement there's an extra View
tag that it shouldn't be there.

Comment: nope it looks fine

Comment: You do not need the brackets. These are only needed if you have multiple methods executed in onPress. So if you just execute one method you do not need the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If the picker run well and return right response, I think it's definitely not Image Picker's fault.